# Intellisense in Razor with Nancy

Tags: c#, .net, razor, nancy

I started a new [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org) project in .Net 4.5.1 using Visual Studio 2013.
As view engine I'm using Razor.
Everything builds and works, but I would like intellisense without using the full namespace.
Is this possible?

This is my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="razor" type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorConfigurationSection, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <razor disableAutoIncludeModelNamespace="false">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="IC.Resources" />
    </assemblies>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="IC.Web.Client.Models" />
      <add namespace="IC.Resources" />
    </namespaces>
  </razor>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor"/>
        <add namespace="IC.Web.Client.Models" />
        <add namespace="IC.Resources" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

If I use code from IC.Resources or IC.Web.Client.Models, I still need to use the full namespace.

This is at the top of my view:

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<IC.Web.Client.Models.LoginModel>
```

It works if I add this to the top of every page:

```
@using IC.Resources;
@using IC.Web.Client.Models
```

But I don't like to repeat this on every page.
I tried adding the using to only the layout page, but that doesn't work.

```
@{ Layout = "_layout.cshtml"; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the System.Object definition to your pageBaseType that should negate the need to add the two using statements.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase`1[[System.Object]]">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: really helpfull ! but can you explain the '`1[[System.Object]]' statement ?

Comment: It's a type definition from somewhere in .net. I've seen this before when i use p.GetType().Name on a generic instance. The original definition would be "Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<System.Object>". Don't ask me why this is.